# x64dbg placing a on write breakpoint on a dynamic allocated address

Tags: disassembly, assembly, x64dbg, crackme

I am currently trying to reverse the registration scheme of a crackme. I found the jump instruction that decides if the title of the program says “registered” or “unregistered” by simply searching for stringreferences. The compare looks like that:

```
cmp byte ptr ds:[eax+0x1620], 0x0
```

The address contained in `eax` is always a different one, which makes it hard to set a breakpoint on the compared address. I already tried to track back `eax`, but that obviously results in hours of work without any result.

Does anybody know a technique to get the part in the disassembly where the program decides whether I am registered or not?

Thanks in advance.

Btw. I am not asking for a crack. I often come across compares like that, and they always discourage me because I don't know what to do there.

Sorry for the broken English.

Comment: I doubt you will get an answer to your question, as piracy is not condoned here. Even if that company went out of business, this still a borderline question :( The answer isn't hard anyway, you could just have a quick google search.

Comment: You are right. I changed the text to a crackme. Could you please tell me the answer if it isn't hard to find. I tried google search for hours and the only recommendations were memory or hardware breakpoints, which obviously won't work here.

Comment: Hardware breakpoints on memory access is the correct answer. I suspect that the address here, is from another module. You can follow it in dump and then check in what module it is located (using the Memory Map tab).

Comment: Okay thanks! It breaks at the right spot but still only sometimes as i already assumed because the address is dynamic. Is there anyway to prevent that?

Comment: You haven't event told me if that's another module... I can only guess what's going one here.. Probably it is due to ASLR, so check the "dll can move" flag (that, if set, will relocate the executable at random). Please be more specific and clear with your questions, otherwise I can only give you a guess.

Comment: First, thanks again for your answer. The place where the eax + 1620 was modified was in the same module as the registration check. The main crackme.exe module. CFF Explorer says that dlls can't move. To give a bit more details to my previous comment I have to say that there were all in all 3 different addresses used to hold the registered boolean. I couldn't tell which one of these 3 was picked after restarting the program. So it is not 100% random. Hope that helps you answering my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is getting really confusing... You said that you are sure that the module is the same, but then you said that the address value is dynamic, then you told me that the address isn't really dynamic but there are 3 different checks that can be executed at runtime.... The only things that I can think to help you are: 1) try to understand how each of these checks is chosen (is it random? put a bp after the call and read the disasm) 2) try to satisfy what each check is trying to verify 3) NOT GOOD: patch these checks

Comment: Also, you know that there are 3 checks, so put a bp on each one and then go backward to understand how that execution flow is chosen.

Comment: You got me wrong there. The address where the registered bool is stored is sometimes 0x031C387C or 0x032C387C or 0x0318387C for example. There are no three checks. I just wonder how x64dbg is supposed to break correctly if the address changes. Surely in this example i was able to break on all three addresses but what if the address is completely random and doesn't follow a pattern.

Comment: Ah, the address of the DATA is changing!! Well, this is actually normal and it isn't a problem at all. If you really want to know where that data is stored, you could always put a breakpoint at that CMP and then do eax+0x1620.

Comment: Yes but when i break at that compare it's already too late. eax+0x1620 is already changed to 0. I have to find out where it gets set to 0. In my opinion that's not possible because i don't know the address.

Comment: There are a couple of methods to do what you are asking for, but they are compilcated to describe here. Anyway, when you said "it is too late, it is already changed to 0" -> you can put an hw breakpoint on "write" on that address and check where it is changed to 0. My idea is that it is initialized to 0 tho.